# Can someone explain why the output is like this?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

```
int one_d[] = {1,2,3};
int main()
{
    int *ptr;
    ptr = one_d;
    ptr += 3;
    printf("%d",*ptr);
    
    return 0;
}
```

The output is 2. But why? I expect that `ptr` has pointed the `one_d[3]` since the last assignment `ptr += 3`. But `one_d` has 3 elements. Can someone explain it to me pls? Thank you so much.

Comment: Your understanding of `*ptr` being equivalent to `one_d[3]` is correct, but `one_d[3]` is accessing the array out of bounds; valid indices are `0`, `1`, and `2`. This is [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior).

Answer (score 1):

Initially, `ptr` is pointing at `one_d[0]` (same as `one_d`), then when you add `3` to `ptr`, you are pointing at `one_d[3]`.

Notice that `one_d` has length `3`, so the last element is at index `2` not `3`. This means `one_d[3]` is out of bounds and can be anything. The fact that it is outputting `2` is random, since it is outputting whatever is 4 bytes behind `one_d[2]`. The fact that you got `2` is just a coincidence.

If you change `one_d` to `one_d[] = {1,2,3,4};`, then your program will output `4`.

Comment: Thx mate for your helping me. If it points an index that is out of bound, so we should expect just a random value right?

Comment: @doguu: You should not "expect" anything when invoking [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) by accessing an array out of bounds.  Anything may happen in that case, including your program crashing. That is the nature of undefined behavior.